# Do isotopes have the same ionization energy?

Tags: ionization-energy, isotope

When learning about isotopes and IE in High School this question have come to my mind recently. I have asked the teacher, she told me that she read articles about it however could not come to a conclusion, given that she doesn't know English, I think her research may be shallow. Nevertheless to put it another words does the neutrons have any effect of the IE particularly the first one?

Comment: No. The ionization energies will be different. However the difference matters most for the light elements. If you think of the Bohr orbit, the orbit's radius depends on the center of mass.

Comment: For questions like these, always start with the simplest possible case. For chemists and physicists, it is deuterium and hydrogen atom. They have slightly different atomic spectrum. It means their ionization energies must be different too (slightly). See another answer https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67489/how-can-difference-in-neutron-number-cause-a-difference-in-ionisation-enthalpies

Comment: The difference is very litte. Between $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{D2}$, the difference is $\approx$ 0.05%, and it is the largest. It is not caused by the electrical charge of the neutron, because it is neutral, but that the common center of mass of the deuterium atom is a little bit more close to the nucleus (in classical mechanical analogy).